# Gridview showing white screen while loading images from sd card

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-gridlayout

I have a gridview when this activity is loading it showing a white screen I checked a lot I don't know why it happening I am showing a gridview of image and those images are from sd card .

**My oncreate code follows**

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) 
        {
            String pdfPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/ICA Faculty/";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),pdfPath+((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.hiddenPdfUrl)).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            try {
                File file = new File(pdfPath+((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.hiddenPdfUrl)).getText());
                Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sorry no PDF reader found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ICA Faculty");

    db.open();
    c = db.getAllRecords();

    //If data exist in local database AND "ICA Faculty" folder exist 
    //Getting the sd card file name from local database
    if (c.moveToFirst() && folder.exists() && folder.listFiles() != null)
    {
        //This array list will help to create image
        imgUrl = new ArrayList<String>();
        pdfUrl = new ArrayList<String>();
                do 
                {          
                    imgUrl.add(c.getString(3));
                    pdfUrl.add(c.getString(2));

                }  while (c.moveToNext());

                ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.this);
                gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You need to sync to create your library.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    db.close();
}
   private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return imgUrl.size();
        //return c.getCount();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        boolean result = ( position == 0 ) ? c.moveToFirst() : c.moveToNext();

        if (result)
        {
            if (convertView == null) 
            {             
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_row_view, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.ImgThumb  = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgThumb);
                holder.Viewcover = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cover);
                holder.PdfUrl    = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.hiddenPdfUrl);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } 
            else 
            {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/ICA Faculty/";

            holder.ImgThumb.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath + imgUrl.get(position)));
            holder.Viewcover.setImageResource(R.drawable.book_cover);
            holder.PdfUrl.setText(pdfUrl.get(position));


        }
        return convertView;
    }
    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView ImgThumb;
        ImageView Viewcover;
        TextView PdfUrl;
    }
}


//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
//=======================================================================================================================================
//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
public static final int progress_bar_type = 0; 
String [] stringArrayPdfUrlForLocalDB;
String [] stringArrayBookId;


//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Method for Sync
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public void libSyc(View v) 
{
    db.open();
    Cursor c = db.getAllRecords();
    if (c.moveToFirst())
    {
        db.deleteAllRecord();
    }
    else{}

    new MyAsyncTask().execute("aa","dd");
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//END Method for Sync
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


// Show Dialog
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case progress_bar_type:
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Making your library. \nPlease wait ...");
        pDialog.setMax(100);
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        pDialog.show();
        return pDialog;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}

//Background Async Task to download file
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread
     * Show Progress Bar Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }

    /**
     * Downloading file in background thread
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;

        for(int i=0 ; i < f_url.length ; i++){

            try {
                URL url = new URL(f_url[i]);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();
                // getting file length
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

                String fpath = getFileName(f_url[i]);
                // Output stream to write file
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/"+fpath);


                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                    // writing data to file
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                // flushing output
                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Updating progress bar
     * */
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // setting progress percentage
        pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task
     * Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
                   //           dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

        //save File Name, Image Name, Book ID to laocal DataBase
        try {
            if(stringArrayPdfUrlForLocalDB.length>0)
            {
                for(int i=0 ; i < stringArrayPdfUrlForLocalDB.length ; i++)
                {
                    //----------------------------------------------------------------
                    //Getting value from string array
                    //----------------------------------------------------------------
                    String fileName = getOnlyFileName(stringArrayPdfUrlForLocalDB[i]);
                    String imageName = getImageName(stringArrayPdfUrlForLocalDB[i]);
                    String BookId   = stringArrayBookId[i];

                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Name: "+fileName+"\nBookId: "+BookId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    //----------------------------------------------------------------
                    //Inserting each File Name, Image Name, Book ID to laocal DataBase
                    //----------------------------------------------------------------
                    db.open();        
                    long id = db.insertRecord(BookId, fileName + ".pdf", imageName);        
                    db.close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not getting any book form server.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            //populate grid view

 //             ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.this);
 //             gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
 //             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            //Reloading activity
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public String getFileName(String wholePath)
    {
        String name=null;
        int start,end;
        start=wholePath.lastIndexOf('/');
        end=wholePath.length();     //lastIndexOf('.');
        name=wholePath.substring((start+1),end);
        //Creating a folder named ICA Faculty
        File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"ICA Faculty");
        directory.mkdirs();

        name = "ICA Faculty/"+name;
        System.out.println("Start:"+start+"\t\tEnd:"+end+"\t\tName:"+name);
        return name;
    }

    public String getOnlyFileName(String wholePath)
    {
        String name=null;
        int start,end;
        start=wholePath.lastIndexOf('/');
        end=wholePath.lastIndexOf('.');
        name=wholePath.substring((start+1),end);

        return name;
    }

    public String getImageName(String wholePath)
    {
        String name=null;
        int start,end;
        start=wholePath.lastIndexOf('/');
        end=wholePath.length();     //lastIndexOf('.');
        name=wholePath.substring((start+1),end);
        //Creating a folder named ICA Faculty
        File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"ICA Faculty");
        directory.mkdirs();

        return name;
    }

}

//===================================================================================================================================
//sending EmailAddress and Password to server
//===================================================================================================================================
 private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{

    String responseBody = null;
    @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        postData(params[0],params[1]);
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), responseBody, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if(responseBody!=null)
        {
            processResponce(responseBody);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Empty Responce.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
    }

    public void postData(String emailId,String passwrd) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    //          HttpPost httppost = new 
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://bumba27.byethost16.com/Ica%20Test/book_lib.xml");
        try {
            // Data that I am sending
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("EmailId", emailId));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", passwrd));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

            Log.d("result", responseBody);
        } 
        catch (Throwable t ) {
            //Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),""+t,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("Error Time of Login",t+"");
        } 
    }
}
//===================================================================================================================================
//END sending EmailAddress and Password to server 
//===================================================================================================================================

//===================================================================================================================================
//processing the XML got from server
//===================================================================================================================================
private void processResponce(String responceFromServer) 
{
    try {
        //saving the file as a xml
        FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("loginData.xml",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        osw.write(responceFromServer);
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();

        //reading the file as xml
        FileInputStream fIn = openFileInput("loginData.xml");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
        char[] inputBuffer = new char[responceFromServer.length()];
        isr.read(inputBuffer);
        String readString = new String(inputBuffer);

        //getting the xml Value as per child node form the saved xml
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(readString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        Document doc = db.parse(is);

        NodeList root=doc.getElementsByTagName("root");
        String loginStatus = null;
        for (int i=0;i<root.getLength();i++) 
        {
            loginStatus = "" + ((Element)root.item(i)).getAttribute("status");
        }

        //If Email and Pass match with server
        if(loginStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("T"))
        {
            NodeList book=doc.getElementsByTagName("book");
            List<String> url = new ArrayList<String>();

            List<String> fileName = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> bkId = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int i=0;i<book.getLength();i++) 
            {
                url.add(((Element)book.item(i)).getAttribute("bookImageUrl"));
                url.add(((Element)book.item(i)).getAttribute("pdfUrl"));

                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                //Creating two list and storing image url, Book Id
                //Logic
                //This 2 list will be accessed and file name, pdf name, book id will be extracted from this 2 value and saved to local DB
                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                fileName.add(((Element)book.item(i)).getAttribute("bookImageUrl"));
                bkId.add(((Element)book.item(i)).getAttribute("bookId"));
            }

            String [] stringArray = url.toArray(new String[url.size()]);

            //Array list is converted to String array
            stringArrayBookId = bkId.toArray(new String[bkId.size()]);
            stringArrayPdfUrlForLocalDB = fileName.toArray(new String[fileName.size()]);

                    //              Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"List Value:\n"+stringArrayPdfUrlForLocalDB.length,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(stringArray);
        }
        else if(loginStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("F"))
        {
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"No Match found for this user",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } 
    catch (Throwable t) 
    {
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),""+t,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("Error On Saving and reading", t+"");
    }

}
```

**Main Activity**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="38sp"
    android:columnWidth="80dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:listSelector="#00000000" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40sp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background_title"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/lib_logo1"
            android:layout_width="40sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4sp"
            android:src="@drawable/book" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/lib_logo2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lib_logo1"
            android:src="@drawable/lib_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sync_img"
            android:layout_width="50sp"
            android:layout_height="50sp"
            android:src="@drawable/sync" 
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:onClick="libSyc"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: But there is no such reply

Comment: sorry I don't know about that but I can't find that option But please don't down vote me I ma new here

Comment: I had deleted that question

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem with ImageAdapter

```
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}
```

You need to return corresponding object for a given position. Return approximate object. Then your GridView contains all objects are null, so thats why your getting empty (white screen).

Comment: May be you need to return an object for a particular index.

Comment: how to do that I am new here please help me out

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to load the images directly in adapter using UI thread,try using Lazyloading concept in android that loads images in seperate thread,this will fix the issue.